# Integrate JSON + Javascript inside website template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am creating online resume with a free template I downloaded.
This template uses bootstrap and displays a progress-bar of my skills.
But now I would like these skills to be changed dynamically using JSON.

I created my file :

```
var Skills = [
{
    "title": "Skill 1",
    "description": "Skill 1 description",
    "value": 100
},
{
    "title": "Skill 2",
    "description": "Skill 2 description",
    "value": 100
}];
```

So it's easy to display it but I would like to format it using the template.

This is an example from the template :

```
<div class="progress-item">
    <span class="progress-title">Skill 1</span>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="62" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 62%"><span class="progress-percent"> 62%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do make title from JSON be linked to class="progress-title"
I did a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/de6f9qwo/37/

Thanks in advance for the help !

[progress-bar preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWIFZ.png)

Comment: your fiddle does nothing

Comment: That is not JSON, that is an Array literal. Also your fiddle doesn't work as you are trying to append invalid html

Comment: Yes my fiddle isn't working because I do not close the first "div" but I need to close it at the end and have no idea of how to do it, this array will be later stored in a specific file

Comment: Well ok my loop is broken cause it adds skills to every progress-item as I need the first one then the second one etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you asked very general question with many different answers,
but the answer to your problem with your open div is something like this :

```js
var Skills = [
{
    "title": "Skill 1",
    "description": "Skill 1 description",
    "value": 100
},
{
    "title": "Skill 2",
    "description": "Skill 2 description",
    "value": 100
}];

$.each(Skills, function (title, val) {
    var $div_item = $('<div class="progress-item"></div>');
    $div_item.append("<span class='progress-title'>" + val.title + "</span>");
    $('.progress-wrapper').append($div_item);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-wrapper"></div>
```

but the real solution for templating is rather a good library like these
https://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396
or read this [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format) to make a proper way of doing it manually.

Comment: Haha I am so dumb. I know understand that I need to use variable. Thanks for the help I appreciate !